# visual basic Combo1.AddItem rs4("holding") wont work why

Tags: vb6

the table name is water and it has two field fname and serial. in the field fname suppose a value 'bill' has 3 serial 1,2 and 3. now i need when i type bill in textbox1 and click search button, the combobox1 should show the serials of 'bill' are 1,2 and 3  .
. m using ms access as db .m using the code but it not working.

is there any other coding to solve this ?

```
Set rs4 = cn.Execute("select fname, serial from water where fname = '" & Text1.Text & "'")
rs4.MoveFirst
```

Do While Not rs4.EOF
    Combo1.AddItem rs4("serial")
    rs4.MoveNext
Loop